# Html Generation from Xml Tree (C#/.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an HTML document stored in memory as an Linq-to-XML object tree.  How can I serialize an XDocument as HTML, taking into account the idiosyncrasies of HTML?

For example, empty tags such as `<br/>` should be serialized as `<br>`, whereas an empty `<div/>` should be serialized as `<div></div>`.

HTML output is possible from an XSLT stylesheet, and `XmlWriterSettings` has an `OutputMethod` property which can be set to HTML - but the setter is `internal`, for use by XSLT or Visual Studio, and I can't seem to find a way to serialize arbitrary XML as HTML.

So, short of using XSLT solely for the HTML output capability (i.e. doing something like running the document through an otherwise pointless chain of XDocument->XmlReader->via XSLT, to HTML), is there a way to serialize a .NET XDocument to HTML?

Comment: Serialize to XHTML, problem solved. Is there any particular reason you want to serialize to old HTML? Also, `<div />` should be equivalent to `<div></div>`...

Comment: @Matt: Perhaps a browser when accepting application/xhtml+xml would understand <div /> correctly otherwise it isn't.  IE won't and doesn't understand application/xhthml+xml either.

Comment: What anthony says goes to the heart of the problem: Xml (really: just a valid tree) is great for *processing*, but HTTP support is poor, so I'd rather not use any form of xml when communicating with a browser just yet.  It's not just browsers; using xml would mean a different content type, which impacts SEO, caching and proxies, so I'd rather avoid these potential pitfalls entirely and use plain old html.

Comment: I still stand by what I said originally. I firmly believe that XHTML is the way forward for HTML. HTML is a mess (as evidenced by the very need for this question). Do the right thing, XHTML, the proper content type and let the browsers worry about their broken implementations. That's the best you can do in any case. IE is just broken in general in my experience.

Comment: Oh, I like XHTML in principle (heck, in my short attempt at blogging I once wrote http://eamon.nerbonne.org/2006/12/why-xhtml-still-serves-purpose.html) - but I see it as a development tool rather than a realistic deployment option.  I don't like IE6, but I'd rather IE6 users see an imperfect but functional layout than a "save as" dialog box.

Comment: @Matt: XHTML is much discussed and has laudable goals but its not commercialy sensible to shrug ones shoulders and say "IE is just broken generally". (current 7% of SO users are using IE6). Its a pain but you have to work with it.

Comment: @Anthony: The fact of the matter though, is that it **is** broken. The fact we still have to work with it is a reality though, as much as I hate to admit it. And people wonder why I'm trying to get out of the web dev market...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.  The XDocument->XmlReader->XSLT is the approach you need.

What you are looking for is a specialised serialiser that arbitarily adds meaning to tag names like `br` and `div` and renders each differently.  One would also expect such a serialiser to work in both directions, IOW be able to read HTML Tag soup and generate an XDocument.  Such a thing does not exist out-of-the-box.

The XmlReader to XSLT seems simple enough for the job, ultimately is just a chain of streams.

Comment: The infuriating thing is that there obviously is support in the box *somewhere* for serializing using html rules - after all, it works from Xslt, and there is that `internal` property.  Also, using XSLT's html output also adds a (generally useless and incorrect) META tag to the document's head.  I'll leave the question open a while longer, but if no one can come up with a better solution, I fear you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

Like you, I'm really surprised that the HTML output method isn't exposed, and I don't know of any way round it, other than the XSLT route you've already identified. When I faced the same problem a couple of years ago, I wrote an XmlWriter wrapper class, that forced calls to WriteEndElement to use WriteFullEndElement on the underlying XmlWriter if the tag being processed wasn't in the list {"area", "base", "basefont", "bgsound", "br", "col", "embed", "frame", "hr", "isindex",   "image", "img", "input", "link", "meta", "param", "spacer", "wbr" }.

This fixed the <div/> problem and was sufficient for me as what I wanted to write was polyglot documents. I didn't find a method to make <br/> appear as <br> but apart from not being able to validate as HTML 4.01 this doesn't cause a real problem. I guess that if you really need this, and don't want to use the XSLT method, you'll have to write your own XmlWriter implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is!

```
//XDocument document; string filename;
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
typeof(XmlWriterSettings).GetField("outputMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(settings, XmlOutputMethod.Html);
using(XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
{
    document.Save(xw);
}
```